# Graph-tool: Look up vertex by user defined labels

Tags: python, graph-tool

I have been using networkx for all my network graphing application so far; however, this new project requires graphs with 10^8 nodes in the graph and networkx was not built to handle this number of nodes (it becomes incredibly slow), so I switched to [graph-tool](https://graph-tool.skewed.de) which seems like it will be much faster.

In using graph-tool I would like to label each vertex in the graph with a user defined systematic label; so that I may look them up by label and not by index. I have tried going over the [documentation](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/index.html), but there doesn't seem to be any support for this; [property maps](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/graph_tool.html#graph_tool.PropertyMap) map from vertex_indices -> values, but I want the reverse.

Is there actual support for this that I am missing? Otherwise is my best option just to create a python dictionary and map labels to vertex_indices that way?

Comment: Can you comment on what the problem was with networkx?  I've used it with networks this size.  It's a bit off your question topic, but what was the problem that was the bottleneck?

Comment: @Joel At around 10^6 nodes it was taking around 10 seconds for networkx to add one node and even more to add an edge (on a 2.4GHz 16-core cpu with 60G RAM machine). I couldn't understand why, until I read up on the documentation and some other posts, which seem to indicate that networkx is really only meant to be optimally used with up to 10^5 nodes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [find_vertex()](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/util.html#graph_tool.util.find_vertex) function. However, it has a O(N) complexity. If you want O(1) lookups you have to construct your own dictionary, like you suggested.